# How to consider the change in categorical variable in multiple linear regression?

Tags: machine-learning, python, regression, prediction, categorical-data

I am building a multiple linear regression model to predict the mileage of tires and one of the independent variables is the wheel position. It is categorical and I could encode it to run the model along with the numerical variables, but then I realized that the tires are being rotated after a certain distance. How do I factor in the change in position?

My table looks somewhat like this. I cannot share the actual values.

| Tyre serial number | Distance covered | Wheel Position | Mileage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (unique for each tyre) | (km) | (FL/FR/RL/RR) | (dependent - float) |
| A1 | 200 | FL |  |
| B1 | 300 | FR |  |
| A1 | 500 | FR |  |
| B1 | 800 | RR |  |

Comment: Can you provide some actual samples from your dataset?

Comment: @spectre, I have edited my post

Comment: "the tyres are being rotated after a certain distance. How do I factor in the change in position?" What do you mean by this? As far as I can see the wheel position has 4 classes namely, FL, FR, RR and RL. Are there any other classes except for these four?

Comment: if there are only 4 classes of wheel position, then just encode them using One Hot Encoder.

Comment: If we take A1, after travelling for 200 kms in position FL, the position is changed to FR and it then travels for 500 kms. The mileage calculated can vary in the two conditions.

Comment: So the A1 value will repeat after some time with just the wheel position changed. Am I right?

Comment: I mean A1 row will repeat after some time with just the wheel position changed. Am I right?

Comment: Yes it will repeat.